# How many discs does Mass Effect 3 have on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-3

I'd like to know how many discs come with the Xbox 360 version of Mass Effect 3.

- Are the game files big enough to require multiple discs?
- Are there separate discs for multiplayer and single-player like Halo 3?
- If there are multiple discs, are they labeled differently in some way?
- Lastly, if there are multiple discs, how are the stored in the case (e.g., stacked on top of each other on a single spool, stored on a separate plastic "page" in the case, etc.)?

*(For an explanation as to why I'd want to know such seemingly mundane information, people selling used copies of games are not awesome at always including everything you expect to come with a game. For example, they may ship without the case. Or just "forget" to include a disc. You really have no way of knowing what's missing or not unless you ask the question above.)*

Comment: why is this question receiving so many downvotes? it seems pretty legit to me.

Comment: Would it be worth rewording the question to include PS3? It seems likely that the answer to both questions is the same.

Comment: I dont think so, generally speaking ps3 and x360 arn't question breaking tags. I really dont know what people didn't like about your question, and considering the upvotes on my comment, others feel the same way I do, your questions fine. I'd just leave it as-is unless a mod comes along with better advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game comes on two discs.  They are labeled "disc 1" and "disc 2."  There is a second disc holder that is snapped into the spine of the case and swings freely, which keeps the two discs apart.  Aside from the two discs, there's a little epilepsy warning card and a card with the game's online pass.  The cover art sheet can be flipped in case you want to see a picture of the "stock" female Shepard on the front instead of the "stock" male Shepard.

I believe the multiplayer is completely on disc 1, although I haven't tested this exhaustively.  The disc is not labeled as such in the case in any way.

I had to switch between discs early in the single player campaign for one of the first side missions.  Going back to the main campaign, however, I had to go back to disc 1.  Expect to switch discs at least somewhat frequently - this isn't like Final Fantasy 7 where you hit a particular part in the plot, change discs, and then don't look back.

Each disc is a separate install if you wish to install it to your hard drive - you'll have to go through the Xbox 360 game install process twice.  Having the discs installed to the drive has not (thus far) removed the need to change out the discs.

Comment: I think you forgot the color and the exact text on each individual disc as well as all the text on the packaging

Comment: Wow two cover art sides. Now thats equality if i've ever seen it.

Comment: @TylerShads, some of this info's actually pretty important...  I would have installed both discs to my drive last night had I known I'd be on disc 2 so quickly.  I had assumed that I could get by with just the first disc for the first half of the game or so.  It's also not without precedent (as is noted in the question) to put the multiplayer component on one of the discs that you can ignore if you just want single player.

Comment: I'm not invalidating it at all, I just like being a prankster ^^